# GoCD Branch Tracking?

Tags: continuous-integration, go-cd

We have a project on Snap CI but since it's going away we have to switch to another tool.
GoCD is our favorite but there is an important feature I am wondering if it's supported: Branch tracking.

Snap CI supports branch tracking which is currently enabled in our project: 'This repository has automatic branch tracking enabled for all branches starting with ***':

[image]
[image]

I tried to set up GoCD to do exactly this. But I couldn't find a way to achieve this behavior. The only thing I found was the feature branch / pull request plugin.
Do you know if such a feature is supported or how I have to configure the FB/PR plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We wanted to do something similar and were faced with the same problem. In the end, we couldn't get direct branch tracking, but created a GoCD API client that created pipelines from a template, and the branch of Git material is set to a parameter (e.g. `#branch`). The client gets run manually when branches are created, but it could quite easily be adapted to run from hooks to automate it.